# .gitignore /folder vs folder/

Tags: git, gitignore

in .gitignore what is the difference between using

```
/bin
```

and

```
bin/
```

And how would I make it so that it removes a certain file, no matter where it is?

```
*/*.ext
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A leading `/` anchors the ignore pattern at the point in the tree where the particular `.gitignore` resides.

A trailing `/` means that a pattern will only match a directory (and so all the files in that matching directory).

You can have both, e.g. `/bin/` will match only a directory called `bin` and only at the level of the `.gitignore` file.

A simple `*.ext` will match any file ending with `.ext` anywhere at or below the level of the `.gitignore` file in which it appears.

Answer (score 5):

The latter would match "xxx/bin" and "bin" in any other subdirectories.

Answer for your edit: `*.ext` would take care of all files in the repository ending w/ that ext.

Comment: Also answer his second question, that is, he should use *.ext instead of */*.ext

Answer (score 5):

I tested the cases and also some more ones and here you can review the results:

[image: Results]

**EDIT**: Corrected according to @Dan Breen's comment below (thanks!)

Comment: In the first row for `bin`, the last column for *.txt should be `x` since it would not be matched.