# Why won't git ignore a bin folder in my submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Git isn't correctly ignoring a bin folder of one of my submodules. Any ideas why?

Here is git status in the submodule:

```
MBPR:$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   bin/
#   gen/
```

Here is git status in the root:

```
MBPR:$ git status
# On branch develop
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   cwac-loaderex (untracked content)
#
```

Here is my .gitignore:

```
MBPR:$ cat .gitignore
.metadata
bin
gen
local.properties
```

This works correctly for other submodules, but for this submodule in particular it refuses to ignore the bin and gen folders. I have deleted and re-added this submodule repeatedly, to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each submodule being a full repo on its own, I would expect a `.gitignore` from a parent repo to *not* apply to a submodule.

That would mean you would need to add a `.gitignore` in the submodule  `cwac-loaderex` in order to actually ignore those directories.

But even if the parent-level `.gitignore` *does* apply to the submodule, its rules (to ignore *directories*) should be:

```
MBPR:$ cat .gitignore
.metadata
bin/
gen/
local.properties
```

Note the '`/`' after `bin` or `gen`.

Comment: is it ok to maintain a top level .gitignore and add `**/bin/`?

Comment: @WeishiZeng Yes, this should work (since git 1.8.2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14931201/6309)