# Adding folders to .gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitignore

Please help me with a git ignoring.

I have files in the public/images directory and don't want to track them. But I need to track files in the /public/images/bonus2 directory. I used this code, and it works.

```
/public/images/
!/public/images/bonus2/
```

But when I try to move tracked files from public/images/bonus2 to public/images/bonus_ordering and make .gitignore like that:

```
/public/images/
!/public/images/bonus2/
!/public/images/bonus_ordering/
```

and make this command:

```
mv public/images/bonus2 public/images/bonus_ordering
```

git track that files in public/images/bonus2 removed, but it don't track that new files public/uploads/bonus_ordering appeared.

I used git add -f public/images/bonus_ordering, but I think that is not good solution. What I need to do instead of that?

Comment: Would that have worked better if you did a `git mv` instead of an `mv`? Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20391855/6309 can be interesting to check.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder - worth reading both top answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the changed .gitignore file and commit it first to take effect.

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "update gitignore"
mv your_file your_new_location
git add .
git commit -m "files moved"
```

Edit: As JonC points out, you don't need to commit the .gitignore file. Adding it is enough for it to take effect.

Comment: Change it first: yes. And and commit, no. You don't need to add and commit for a `.gitignore` to be taken into account right away. But it is still a good idea in order to not loose your modifications on the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @VonC I actually had a doubt about that. But I answered with commit to be on the safer side.