# Why are these files not ignored by git?

Tags: xcode, git

My `.gitignore` file contains these lines :

```
 xcuserdata/**/*
 !xcuserdata/**/xcschemes/*
```

But the following file is still tracked
`/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/colas.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints.xcbkptlist`

Why is it so? How can I fix that?

PS: If I had `MyApp.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/colas.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger`, the files are ignored. But I don't understand why it does not ignore them without this "hack".

---

### EDIT 1

Contrary to what is said in one of the answer, the pattern

```
 xcuserdata/**/*
 !xcuserdata/**/xcschemes/*
```

works !!! I mean, the files under `/xcschemes` are tracked.

See also the post [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects/12021580#12021580), where I get this `.gitignore` file.

### EDIT 2

My `Git` version is `1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)`.

### EDIT 3

When I `git check-ignore` this file, here is what I get

```
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

But the fact is that a parent directory is a git directory...

### EDIT 4

When I `git check-ignore --no-index --` this file, here is what I get

```
[MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeSnippetsHelper.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2014-02-10 10:03:50.856 xcodebuild[1496:d07] XcodeColors: load (v10.1)
2014-02-10 10:03:50.859 xcodebuild[1496:d07] XcodeColors: pluginDidLoad:
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

### EDIT 4bis

From the root folder :

- if I don't use the `no-index` option, there is no reply to `git check-ignore`.
- if I use the `no-index` option: I get the error `error: unknown option 'no-index'`...

Strange ;-!

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: ok, I know there were some recent fixes around '**' pattern, so it would be interesting to see if the issue persists with a 1.8.5.x version.

Comment: Can you try a `git check-ignore --no-index -- yourFile`? It
 can be used to diagnose which paths that should have been ignored
 have been mistakenly added to the index.

Comment: Adn try to use git check-ignore (with or without the --no-index option) from the root folder of your git repo, with the full path of the file: `cd /MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj ; git check-ignore -- xcuserdata/colas.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints.xcbkptlist`

Answer (score 6):

First, you can do a **[`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)** (git 1.8.3.3+) to see what rule is ignoring your file (assuming it wasn't in the index in the first place)

Second, read "[`.gitignore` exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)":

> **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded**. (`*`)
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.8+, see below)
>   Git doesn't list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

So the file of `xcschemes` wouldn't be un-ignored anyway.
You needed to [ignore parent folder per parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/6309).
But a better approach is to ignores files only, and then exclude the folder:

```
xcuserdata/**
!xcuserdata/**/
!xcuserdata/**/xcschemes/**
```

Remember:

You need to *exclude folders* from the `gitignore` rules before being able to exclude files.

---

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

However:

> The directory part in the re-include rules must be literal (i.e. no wildcards)

So that wouldn't have worked here anyway.

Comment: I tried to change to your suggestion. The file still appears in SourceTree as "not tracked"... Thanks for your help!! I also did the `git check-ignore` (see my edit).

Comment: I tried from the root folder, and with the `no-index` option. The results are different. If you have any clue of what's going on...

Comment: @Colas regarding the error message with the --no-index option, is it possible your version of Git is a bit too old to support it? Because it was introduced in 1.8.5 only.

Answer (score 0):

Adding file names to `.gitignore` helps prevent you from adding the files unintentionally.
If you do something like `git add .` to add a folder full of files to the repository, the files (or filetypes) ignored in `.gitignore` will not be added.
They would have to be added by using the `-f` flag with the `git add` command.
It will not change anything if the files are already tracked.

You can stop tracking the files by using the answer to the question:
[Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)

edit: After rereading the question a few more times, I think you may be having roughly the same issue that was addressed in this answer:
[.gitignore - ignore any 'bin' directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory)