# gitignore everything except specific files

Tags: git, gitignore

I've been reading on Stack Overflow about using gitignore to ignore everything except specific files. I've tried a bunch of different suggestions, but I can't get it to work for me.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I want to exclude everything except one file in my main directory and a couple other files in the subdirectory. So, I want only these files:

```
flightsofideas.rb
/FlightsOfIdeas/svgExportTools.rb
/FlightsOfIdeas/svgExport.rb
```

My latest version of gitignore is:

```
*    
!flightsofideas.rb
!/FlightsOfIdeas/svgExportTools.rb
!/FlightsOfIdeas/svgExport.rb
```

But git only includes `flightsofideas.rb`, it doesn't get the files in the subdirectory.

Comment: what does `git check-ignore -v -- FlightsOfIdeas/svgExport.rb` returns? (and what git version are you using?)

Comment: Maybe this is because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309?

Comment: It returns this:
.gitignore:5:* FlightsOfIdeas/svgExport.rb.  My Git version is: git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)

Comment: Can't you use a wildcard or something? That'd be a really nice feature of Git.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `!*/` not to ignore the directories, or it will not look into the directories to include back files.

Still similar problem as [What's the difference between Git ignoring directory and directory/*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715898/whats-the-difference-between-git-ignoring-directory-and-directory/25716803#25716803).

```
*
!*/
!/flightsofideas.rb
!/FlightsOfIdeas/svgExportTools.rb
!/FlightsOfIdeas/svgExport.rb
```