# What's the difference between Git ignoring directory and directory/*?

Tags: git, gitignore, notation, dotfiles

I'm confused about what's the correct way to ignore the contents of a directory in git.

Assume I have the following directory structure:

```
my_project  
     |--www  
         |--1.txt  
         |--2.txt
     |--.gitignore
```

What's the difference between putting this:

```
www
```

And this?

```
www/*
```

The reason I'm asking this question is: In git, if a directory is empty, git won't include such empty directory in repository. So I was trying the solution that is add an extra .gitkeep file under the directory so that it won't be empty. When I was trying that solution, if in the .gitignore file, I write like below:

```
www
!*.gitkeep
```

It doesn't work(My intention is to ignore all contents under www but keep the directory). But if I try the following:

```
www/* 
!*.gitkeep
```

Then it works! So I think it must has some differences between the two approaches.

Comment: A simple difference between `bin` and `bin/` is that the former will ignore files or folders, the latter only folders. I don't know the difference with `bin/*`

Answer (score 204, accepted):

There're differences among `www`, `www/` and `www/*`.

**Basically from the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and my own tests, `www` find a match with a file or a directory, `www/` only matches a directory, while `www/*` matches directories and files inside `www`.**

I'll only discuss on the differences between `www/` and `www/*` here, since the differences between `www` and `www/` are obvious.

For `www/`, git ignores the directory `www` itself, which means git won't even look inside. But for `www/*`, git checks all files/folders inside `www`, and ignores all of them with the pattern `*`. It seems to lead to the same results since git won't track an empty folder `www` if all its child files/folders are ignored. And indeed the results will be no difference for OP's case with `www/` or `www/*` standalone. But it does make differences if it's combined with other rules.

For example, what if we want to only include `www/1.txt` but ignore all others inside `www`?

The following `.gitignore` won't work.

```
www/
!www/1.txt
```

While the following `.gitignore` works, why?

```
www/*
!www/1.txt
```

For the former, git just ignores the directory `www`, and won't even look inside to include `www/1.txt` again. The first rule excludes the parent directory `www` but not `www/1.txt`, and as a result `www/1.txt` cannot be "**included again**".

But for the latter, git first ignores all files/folers under `www`, and then includes one of them again which is `www/1.txt`.

For this example, the follwing lines in the documentation may help:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not
>   possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is
>   excluded.

Comment: Don't you think that `www/1.txt` and then `www/` would do the same as the second approach...

Answer (score 8):

I'm just parsing through the documentation, and as far as I can tell they only differ in more advanced patterns, e.g.

```
$ cat .gitignore
    # exclude everything except directory foo/bar
    /*
    !/foo
    /foo/*
    !/foo/bar
```

I *did* test the above, and if you replace `!/foo` with `!/foo/*`, you do indeed get a different result.

Note

```
foo
```

Will exclude any file `foo`, but

```
foo/
```

will only exclude directories named foo.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the perfectly good answers you have already obtained, you should note that you can have `.gitignore` anywhere in your project, including subfolders.

So if you want to ignore all files inside `www`, but whant the `www` folder to be versioned, instead of using an empty `.gitkeep`, `.dummy` or whatever name you choose, why not use a `.gitignore` there, telling to ignore all files?

```
/
|- .gitignore   (a)
\- www
    |- .gitignore   (b)
    |- 1.jpg
    \- 2.jpg
```

In the root `.gitignore` (a), you don't say anything about the `www` folder or its contents.

In the `www/.gitignore` (b) you put the following:

```
# ignore all files in this folder except this .gitignore
*
!.gitignore
```

This way everything looks more organized (to me at least).

Answer (score 1):

To ignore everything in a directory except dotfiles you can use the following glob-pattern in your `.gitignore`:

```
www/[^.]*
```

So no need for an extra `.gitignore`, just simply add a `.keep` file to your `www` directory.