# How to quickly incorporate all untracked files and directories in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a large Git repository that has many random files and directories in it that should be ignored.  When I run `git status`, I get a lot of noise.

Those files and directories don't follow a specific pattern.  I could manually add them one by one to `.gitignore`, but this is tedious.

Is there a rapid way to add many or all of the "untracked files" returned by `git status` to `.gitignore`?  This seems like such an obvious task that I imagine a solution must exist.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. In the `.gitignore` file, you can ignore a lot of things all in one go, only to "unignore" some of them further down the file; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715898/whats-the-difference-between-git-ignoring-directory-and-directory). For a more specific answer than this, though, you would need to tell us about the structure of your working tree.

Comment: Why not highlight and copy all the filepaths (at once) from `git status`'s output and paste them into your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: It might help to organize your ignored files better, keeping them in a single ignored subfolder.

Comment: Someone edited the title of my question, but it now no longer really reflects my original intention.  Perhaps a better title would be "How to include all untracked files in .gitignore?"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple Git alias, and then call it like this:

**Edited:** In reponse to ddd kkk's comment

```
git config alias.ignore-untracked "! git status -s | grep '??' | perl -pe 's/.{3}/\//' >>  .gitignore"
git ignore-untracked
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Joseph Strauss's solution, the final alias definition I am using is:

```
git config alias.ignore-untracked "! git status -s | grep '??' | cut -d\  -f2- | awk '{print \"/\" \$0; }' | sed '1i # ignore-untracked: $(date)' >> .gitignore"
```

This prepends the additions to gitignore with a comment that indicates the date the files were added.

This code is executed as follows:

```
git ignore-untracked
```