# How do a ignore a certain disk pattern in .gitignore?

Tags: git

I have a lot of paths that contain build specific data:

```
a/b/c/d/SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER/
a/e/f/SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER/
a/g/i/a/b/c/d/SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER/
```

I would like to ignore all folders SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER and their content using a pattern-type solution (as there are hundreds of such SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER folders)

Is that possible in .gitignore?

Comment: I think you just want to add the line `SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER` to your `.gitignore`. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into your `.gitignore`:

```
SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER/
```

More info:

- [the git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
- [What's the difference between Git ignoring directory and directory/*?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25715898/139010)
- [How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8527597/139010)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following could work for this.

```
**/SOME_RECURRING_FOLDER/**
```