.gitignore, difference between dir, dir/ and dir/*
In .gitignore what's the difference between
dir

dir/

dir/*

?
As more real-life scenario, consider config instead of dir, when there are config-dirs and config-files

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25716803/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+difference

dir: Ignores any file or directory named dir at any level.
dir/: Ignores the dir directory and all its contents at the root level.
dir/*: Ignores all files and directories inside the root-level dir, but not dir itself.
