# Add files to Git in an ignored directory

Tags: git

I am trying to include a couple of files which are in an ignored directory, but get the following.  How do I include them?  Thank you

```
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$ git add html/about-us.html
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
html/about-us.html
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$
```

My `.gitignore` file

```
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$ cat .gitignore
/html/
/ayb_cache/
/ayb_resources/

#Some cache files in the main application
/ayb_application/lib/plugins/tinymce_plugins/imageManager/cache/
/ayb_application/lib/plugins/tinymce_plugins/image_purchased/cache/
/ayb_application/lib/plugins_3rd/tinymce_4.0.6/plugins/image/cache/

# Temp files often created by editors
*.~

# Track some files in html directory
!/html/css/
!/html/images/
!/html/scripts/
!/html/about-us.html
!/html/corporate.php
!/html/index.html
!/html/muse_manifest.xml
!/html/terms-and-conditions.html
[Michael@devserver bidjunction]$
```

Comment: You can `git add --force yourFile` to force a file to be added to git regardless of `.gitignore`.

Comment: @Seiyria.  Yes, I saw the response, but wondered why I was doing something that required a force.

Comment: You are ignoring the html directory. Is this really that surprising?

Comment: The first line should be `/html/*`

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci.  Thank you.  I read other similar SO posts, but this one hit home.

Comment: That should be easier to do with git 2.8 (March 2016). See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23454246/6309)

Answer (score 2):

[Shawn Balestracci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2197771/shawn-balestracci) mentioned (in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451849/add-files-to-git-in-an-ignored-directory/23454246#comment35949487_23451849)) "[`.gitignore` exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/6309)", which illustrated what I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309):

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. (`*`)
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.?, see below)

(A message [introduced with git 1.9.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309))

If you exclude `html/*`, you are excluding content, not the folder itself, allowing the `!xxx` rules to apply.

Note that to check at all time why a particular file is ignored, you can type:

```
git check-ignore -v -- html/about-us.html
```

That will give you the exact line of your `.gitignore` file which is the cause of your `git add` not working.

---

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

In your case, what could work (with git 2.?+) would have be:

```
/html
!/html/css
!/html/images
!/html/scripts
!/html/about-us.html
!/html/corporate.php
!/html/index.html
!/html/muse_manifest.xml
!/html/terms-and-conditions.html
```

Comment: thank you for that `/*` which was the key!