# How can I add files with specific extension to git repository from subdirectories without adding the subdirectory itself?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Let's say that I have a directory called REPO with an initiated git repo in it, in that directory, there's 2 subdirectories called `sub1`, `sub2` and a "`1.cpp`" file.
`sub1` has "`2.cpp`" file and other files.
`sub2` has "`3.cpp`" file and other files, so It'll be exactly like this diagram

[image]

Now I want only these files in my repository without any directories

```
1.cpp
2.cpp
3.cpp
```

I know how to ignore all files except `.cpp` files using `.gitignore` but I don't want `sub1` and `sub2` to be included in my repo, I only want the `cpp` files in them, I have searched a lot but couldn't find an answer, I hope I could explain it properly.

Comment: So you want to keep the directory structure in file system while ignore directory structure in repo?

Comment: Yeah that's it exactly

Comment: I don't know how it is possible. But like in Xcode, you can create some fake directory in IDE, so when you are working it seems those files are in different directories. But in this way both the filesystem and git don't know these directories.

Answer (score 2):

You can move them:

```
cd /path/to/REPO
git mv sub1/2.cpp .
git mv sub2/3.cpp .
```

And then remove the subfolders if you don't need them.

But actually, the OP meant:

> I simply want Git to include all my .cpp files from all subdirectories and add them to the repository.
>
> know how to ignore all files except .cpp files using .gitignore but I don't want sub1 and sub2 to be included in my repo, I only want the cpp files in them

If you haven't added any file yet, your `.gitignore` would be

```
**
!**/
!*.cpp
```

Then a `git add .` would include only cpp files.
You ignore all files (`**`), then exclude folders (`!**/`): that allows you to then exclude `.cpp` files (`!*.cpp`) from the gitignore rule.
That is because [**it is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309).

Comment: It's a Visual Studio C++ project so I only want to include .cpp files because nothing else matters for me, so unfortunately I can't move files to repo directory.

Comment: @MohamedMagid Sure, you can work with Git from the command-line with Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/command-prompt

Comment: @MohamedMagi and you could do that through a Windows Explorer as well: see my edited answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that I got your point, I can't move source files as visual studio won't be able to read them, I simply want Git to include all my .cpp files from all subdirectories and add them to the repository.

Comment: @MohamedMagid Got it, I misinterpreted your question at first. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks that's so close to my point, I just want the subdirectory itself get excluded but not its files, so if I push the repo to a remote repo I get all .cpp files in one place without going to subdirectories

Comment: @MohamedMagid Wait, are those files supposed to *move* somehow, or can they stay where they are, in there subfolder, but without any other files?

Comment: @MohamedMagid In other words, anyone cloning your repo will get what you put in it, exactly as you put it (the files remains in their folder)

Comment: Yeah that was my point, I wanted anyone clones it to only get file.cpp not directory/file.cpp but thanks anyway you helped a lot

Comment: @MohamedMagid Mmm... that doesn't sound like something Git could do natively. You mentioned XCode, but that is an IDE. Maybe an IDE can filter and present you those files that way (no subfolder). But Git is much more basic: it gives you back what you put in it.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the folders in the repository, move the files using git to repo directory level

```
git add sub1
git mv sub1/2.cpp .
git mv sub2/3.cpp .
```

you do not need to remove the directory considering that it is empty. Commit it after adding.