# gitignore pattern to include all directories with a specific sub directory

Tags: c++, git, github, gitignore, openframeworks

I am trying to setup a .gitignore file for openFrameworks. I have a folder that contain project folders - each one has a src directory. I would like to include the folder itself and the src directory only for every project.

Here is my current .gitignore file

```
# ignore these files
# ignoring everything except spec items
*

# allow these files
!.gitignore
!/README.md
!/*/src
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ideally I would like the committed folder structure to look something like this:

```
.
├── project_1
│   └── src
│       └── file.cpp
├── project_2
│   └── src
│       └── file.cpp
└── project_3
    └── src
        └── file.cpp
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore files *and* folders (with '`*`'), you won't be able to exclude sub-folders.

The rule to remember remains:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**

Try instead ignoring files only.

```
**
```

Then you can exclude subfolders like src:

```
!.gitignore
!/README.md
!src/
# or, to be more specific
!/*/src
```

For any element that would be *still* ignored, check what rule is involved with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- an/ignored/element
```