# Storage link is not included when doing a Git push Laravel

Tags: laravel, git, gitlab, laravel-5.7

I just have done a `git push` in our online repo

When I checked the online repo and checked the `public` folder it shows this:
[image]

while in my local repo I have this in my `public` folder:

[image]

My local has Storage folder from my storage link. I am guessing that this has something to do with the `.gitignore` inside my local `public` folder. It contains:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Same goes with my storage folders. In our Online repo inside `storage/app/public`:
[image]

while in my local `storage` folder:

[image]

`user_images` is present in my local repo. Here is the inner `.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

and the outer `.gitigore`:

```
*
!public/
!.gitignore
```

I am not quite familiar with setting rules in `.gitignore`. I wish to make sure that whatever my local Storage and public folder has, the Online repo has as well. How should I go about in doing this?

Kindly edit my tags if it is misleading or incorrect. Thank you.

This is the content of the root `.gitignore`:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

I have removed `/public/storage` in `.gitignored` and tried to do a `git push`

```
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   .gitignore
```

and still, nothing is the same from my local to Online repo? Anything I might have missed?

Tried running `git check-ignore -v path/to/file`

In my root `.gitignore`:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

If I ran `git check-ignore -v public/hot`, it replies with `.gitignore:2:/public/hot        public/hot` but if I ran `git check-ignore -v public/storage`, it doesn't respond with anything which it should because it is included in root `.gitignore` I come to believe that this situation made it impossible for the `public/storage/user_images` and `storage/app/public/user_images`. Any help is needed.

I may have been viewing a wrong file or path all this time. But I can confirm that @VonC method helped me do a proper exclusion in `gitignore`. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Final gitignores so far

root `.gitignore`:

```
/node_modules
# /public/hot
# /public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

storage\app.gitignore

```
# *
# !public/
!.gitignore
```

storage\app\public.gitignore

```
# *
!.gitignore
```

public\storage.gitignore

```
# *
!.gitignore
```

Just an additional info:

`git check-ignore -v vendor` gives `.gitignore:5:/vendor    vendor`

while `git check-ignore -v /vendor` gives `fatal: C:/Program Files/Git/vendor: 'C:/Program Files/Git/vendor' is outside repository`

I'm not sure where `git check-ignore -v` path points to.

Comment: The storage folder inside your local screenshot has user uploaded images. I do not think that will be a a good data to push into repo, why is it needed?

Comment: because in my project, if the user doesn't upload an image, that `noimage.jpg` will be used as default. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Is there a way we can include `noimage.jpg` as an exemption? or if not at least everything else in my local reflects exactly to the online repo?

Comment: What is the content of ,gitignore inside the laravel root?

Comment: I have included the contents of root `.gitignore` in my post. I hope it helps.

Comment: you have `/public/storage` in .gitignore and hence the storage folder is ignored in the push :)

Comment: Oh I see, so it goes without saying that I should also remove `/storage/*.key` to reflect all my local folders in storage to online storage folder? Or the `/public/storage` is enough to solve both `public` and `storage` folder synching?

Comment: I would say move the image outside storage folder and put it inside public/img folder

Comment: wait why? That would cause all my `img src` path to mess up? Is there a way to exclude storage folder altogether?

Comment: If you really want then you can just remove the `public/storage` entry from gitignore and push  the changes. It will automatically show you to add the storage folder it will show in red as untracked.

Comment: I will try that as recommended, I'll also see if it includes the `noimage.jpg`

Comment: Updated result in the post

Comment: Now if you do git status, can you see public/storage in red ?

Comment: Yes it says: `Changes not staged for commit: modified:   .gitignore`

Comment: do `git add .gitignore public/storage` and `git push`

Comment: after doing `git push` it said `Everything up-to-date` and when i did a `git status` it says `Changes to be committed: modified:   .gitignore` in green color.

Comment: ohh did you do git commit after add and before push?

Comment: Do not keep resources in storage. Add a new folder under assets which you copy on build to the public folder.

Comment: @MihirBhende I did a `git add .gitignore public/storage`, `git commit -m "test"`, `git push` and checked online repo but it still has no `public\storage\user_images` and `storage\app\public\user_images` where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, for any *file* ignore within a folder, type:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file
```

That will display exactly which `.gitignore` is responsible for ignoring said file.

Second, the rule of gitignore is simple:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**

To exclude files (or all files) from a subfolder of an ignored folder `f`, you would do:

```
f/**
!f/**/
!f/a/sub/folder/someFile.txt
```

Meaning: you need to whitelist *folders* first, before being able to exclude from gitignore *files*.

Comment: I did `git check-ignore -v storage/app/user_images` and it responded `storage/app/.gitignore:1:*      storage/app/user_image` so what i did is commented the `# *` so upon doing a `check-ignore` again nothing showed. proceeded in doing a: `git add *`, `git commit -m "test"`, `git push` but still the online repo has no  `storage/app/user_images` directory. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @JustinF As long as nothing shows, keep doing `git check-ignore -v`: you will see what rule block. Then re-read the rule I mention: any folder content ifnored is generally ignored because a *parent* folder was already ignored itself.

Comment: something weird is happening. I edited root `.gitignore` in my project, I have these two lines: `/public/hot`, `/public/storage` when I check-ignore public/hot is replies `.gitignore:2:/public/hot        public/hot` but if I check-ignore public/storage it does not reply anything even though it is clearly included in the `.gitignore` file. Is there anything unusual happening here?

Comment: @JustinF Check-ignore a *file*: Git does not version folders. As a best practice, when ignoring folders (content), always put a trailing '/' in your .gitignore rules (for folders): `/public/storage/` or `/public/hot/`

Comment: @JustinF Also, what were the final gitignore rules you have set up?

Comment: @JustinF I confirm the check-ignore only takes *relative* paths from the root of the git repo, not absolute paths.

Comment: Can you explain further what it was meant by _relative_ paths from the root? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: @JustinF in your case, if you `cd` to the root folder of your repo, the `git check-ignore` command would use `public/storage` (relative to that current folder), *not* `/public/storage`.

Comment: basically `git check-ignore` means `project-name/` and not just `project-name` (without slash)? is this correct?

Comment: @JustinF means `afile`, or `afolder/`, in that (for the folder case) `git check-ignore` will test if *files* within that folder are ignored by a `.gitignore` rule.  But in both cases, the path to a file (or the path to a folder) passed as an argument would be relative to your current folder, inside the repo.

Answer (score 2):

For those who might still be searching for an answer, edit the .gitignore files in storage/app and storage/app/public folders and remove the first 2 lines from each.