# .gitignore track only one file in a directory at any depth

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to ignore all but a single file in a named directory that could be at any depth.  So in a structure like this, I want to track any occurrence of build/.gitkeep but ignore all other files in and below build/.  The items to track are marked with ++.  The items to ignore are marked with --.

```
    |.gitignore                               ++
    |Makefile                                 ++
    |--build/                                 ++
    |--build/.gitkeep                         ++
    |--build/ignore_any_file                  --
    |--build/ignore_any/dir                   --
    |--foo/                                   ++
    |--foo/file_to_keep                       ++
    |--foo/dir_to_keep/                       ++
    |--foo/dir_to_keep/stuff                  ++
    |--foo/build/                             ++
    |--foo/build/.gitkeep                     ++
    |--foo/build/ignore_any_file              --
    |--foo/build/ignore_any/dir               --
    |--foo/build/ignore_any/dir/subir         --
    |--bar                                    ++
    |--bar/file_to_keep                       ++
    |--bar/dir_to_keep/                       ++
    |--bar/dir_to_keep/stuff                  ++
    |--bar/build/                             ++
    |--bar/build/.gitkeep                     ++
    |--bar/ignore_any_file                    --
    |--bar/ignore_any/dir                     --
    |--bar/ignore_any/dir/subir               --
    |--foobar/foo                             ++
    |--foobar/foo/file_to_keep                ++
    |--foobar/foo/dir_to_keep/                ++
    |--foobar/foo/dir_to_keep/stuff           ++
    |--foobar/foo/build/                      ++
    |--foobar/foo/build/.gitkeep              ++
    |--foobar/foo/build/ignore_any_file       --
    |--foobar/foo/build/ignore_any/dir        --
    |--foobar/foo/build/ignore_any/dir/subir  --
```

I have tried many, many combinations.  The sticking point for me seems to be having build/ at any depth.  I am trying to avoid have to create entries for every path where build/ exists.  I also don't want to create .gitignore files in every instance of build/.

```
    $ git --version
    git version 2.20.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make sure to exlude *folders* from your ignore rule, if you want then to be able to exclude a file:

```
build/**
!build/**/
!build/**/.gitkeep
```

This is because:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)

In your case (build at any depth)

```
**
!**/
!build/.gitkeep
!**/build/.gitkeep
```

The [OP nelsonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131659/nelsonov) made it work ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274320/gitignore-track-only-one-file-in-a-directory-at-any-depth/62275693?noredirect=1#comment110142565_62275693)) with:

```
build/** 
!build/**/ 
!build/ 
!build/.gitkeep 
!**/build/ 
!**/build/.gitkeep 
**/build/**
```

Comment: In your version, I still get build/file and build/dir/ (but not build/dir/file).  It looks like I am still getting one layer that I shouldn't.  I am familiar with the concept that something can not be re-included after the parent is excluded, but I seem to not be excluding enough.

Comment: @nelsonov OK, what about my second proposal in my edited answer?

Comment: The results seem the same for me.  Here's some examples of files showing up as untracked (that should be ignored):
 `GatewayESP8266-nrf24/build/file
 GatewayESP8266-nrf24/build/somedir/
 GatewayESP8266-rfm95/build/
 mysensors-eeprom/build/EEProm.ino.eep
 mysensors-eeprom/build/build.options.json
 mysensors-eeprom/build/core/`

Comment: @nelsonov where is your .gtiignore? I just tested it, and it works perfectly. No lower `build` folders are detected, even if they include a `.gitkeep`. What version of Git are you using? On which OS?

Comment: git version 2.20.1 on Linux (Rasbian 10 and Debian 10)
.gitignore is in the root of git repository

To clarify (maybe necessarily) I want to track every instance of `build/.gitkeep` at any depth but ignore anything else in `build/` at any depth.

Comment: @nelsonov OK, my second config tracks `.gitkeeps` only the main `build/` folder, not `.gitkeep ` in any `build/` subfolder

Comment: Other portions of my .gitignore work as expected:
`secrets.h`
`build/**`
`!build/`
`!build/.gitkeep`
`*~`
`*elf`
`*bin`
`*hex`

I don't know how to get the linebreaks to remain.  Please assume they are there.

Comment: I don't know what to do then.  I'm still seeing the results indicated above.  BTW, there won't be an instance of `build` under `build`, but that's not the important part.  I still see `path/build/file` and `path/build/dir/` as untracked.  It does ignore `path/build/dir/anything`   The whole point of the ,gitkeeps, btw, is just to keep otherwise empty `build/` and `path/build` for templating.

Comment: @nelsonov `BTW, there won't be an instance of build under build`: OK I have fixed that in my latest edit. But try and check what is and is not ignore with `git check-ignore -v -- a/file`. And, if possible, upgrade to Gti 2.27.

Comment: @nelsonov I have edited further the rules at the end of the answer: Give it another try.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me:
`build/**
!build/**/
!build/
!build/.gitkeep
!**/build/
!**/build/.gitkeep
**/build/**
`

Do you want to update you answer or would you prefer to keep it as is?  I wouldn't have gotten here without you.

Comment: @nelsonov Thank you for the feedback: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.