# Trouble with ".gitignore"

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like to ignore some particular files from committing bundle,
so included them into project's ".gitignore" file:

```
MDK-ARM/test1_prj/
!MDK-ARM/test1_prj/*.hex
!MDK-ARM/test1_prj/*.axf
MDK-ARM/JLinkLog.txt
```

But unfortunately, the last line doesn't work, and consistently included in commits, can't explain why.

Another question is how to ignore changing .gitignore itself (except hiding 'em)

*PS: Briefly saying I want to exclude all compiling and debugging junk except the resulting files.*

Comment: “consistently included in commits” That is correct behaviour. If a file has been included in a commit, it keeps on being included, and _.gitignore_ has no effect on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the file is not already tracked:

```
git rm --cached -- MDK-ARM/JLinkLog.txt
```

Second, if a folder is ignored, all the other rules regarding files inside that folder won't matter.
**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**.

You need to blocklist *files*, not folders, before grantlisting exceptions.

```
MDK-ARM/test1_prj/**
!MDK-ARM/test1_prj/**/
!MDK-ARM/test1_prj/*.hex
!MDK-ARM/test1_prj/*.axf
```

Finally, check those rules do apply with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- MDK-ARM/test1_prj/a_File_Which_Should_Be_Ignored
```

If it is ignopred, you will see the `.gitignore` file involved, and its ignore rule line number.

Comment: Grantlist/Blocklist from https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/133489