# Exclude a specific file Loader.php from Zend folder under vendor folder

Tags: php, magento, server, gitignore

Below is the entry I added in .gitignore to exclude Load.php file so that any change to this file is tracked. I don't seem to find the mistake in my rules. Please help me figure it out.

Path to the file: `public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend`

```
/public_html/vendor
!/public_html/vendor/magento

/public_html/vendor/magento/*
!/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1

/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/*
!/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library

/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/*
!/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend

/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/*
!public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Loader.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add at least `!/public_html/vendor/*/`:

```
/public_html/vendor/*
!/public_html/vendor/*/
!public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Loader.php
```

(no trailing slash after `Loader.php`, since it is a file, not a folder)

If you do not whitelist folders (here, subfolders of `vendor/`), you won't be able to exclude files, since the parent folders are ignored.

The general rule is:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**

Double-check with [`git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

Also, make sure the file was not already tracked:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git rm --cached  -- public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Loader.php
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. Do I need to do cache:clean to see it changed?

Comment: @PramodGangadar First, did you try the `git rm --cached` command, to make sure it was not tracked?

Comment: Yes  I tried at Magento root and received the message saying it didn't find any matching file

Comment: @PramodGangadar But, from the same root folder, `ls public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Loader.php` does work, right?

Comment: @PramodGangadar If ls works, what does `git check-ignore -v -- public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Loader.php` return?

Comment: It returned `.gitignore:180:/public_html/vendor      Loader.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248169/discussion-between-pramod-gangadar-and-vonc).