# How to .gitignore all files except old and new files with a given file extension

Tags: git

I have a project directory with multiple subdirectories that contain various files with distinct file extensions. Let's say I only want to track Python source files (*.py) and C++ source files (*.cpp).

I tried this:

```
# ignore all files ...
*.*

# ... except these
!.gitignore     # .gitignore file
!*.py           # python source files
!*.cpp          # c++ source files
```

This keeps track of the correct files that are already in the repository; however, the problem is that VSCode won't automatically track new files that I add to the project, even if they are *.py or *.cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is that I was actually using inline comments, which now I realize are not allowed. This now works:

```
# ignore all files ...
*.*

# ... except these:

# .gitignore file
!.gitignore

# python source files
!*.py

# c++ source files
!*.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Using exception rules ("ignore all except xx") means following the rule

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**

You can check if your new *.py files are still ignored with [`git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/new/file.py`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore).

Add a whitelist rules for *folders*

```
# ignore all files ...
*.*

# whitelist folder
!*/

# ... except these files
!.gitignore     # .gitignore file
!*.py           # python source files
!*.cpp          # c++ source files
```

Comment: I tried adding `!*/` as you show; I also tried adding `!*/` + `!*/path/to/folder/containing/file/` but is still ignored. Running `git check-ignore` returns: `.gitignore:2:*.*        ./path/to/folder/containing/file/new_file.py`.

Comment: Ok I found the problem: I actually had inline comments, which now I realise are not allowed.

Comment: @Carlos That should work indeed, considering the `*.*` first rule might not ignore folders themselves.